# Convert date to equivalent BC date in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have date in the form `March, 01 0201 00:00:00+0000` in PostgreSQL. I want to cast this date to an equivalent "BC" (Before Christ) date - is it possible to do so directly in PostgreSQL?

For example, I want to convert `March, 01 0201 00:00:00+0000` to `March, 01 0201 BC 00:00:00+0000` i.e. just convert 1 date into another date in BC. Is it possible to do so directly in PostgreSQL without converting the date into a literal first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so - this is basically a textual transformation you are trying to do. There's no simple mathematical connection between the two dates.

You can of course wrap the lot up in a function to make it cleaner in your code.